# How to add to collection using reflection - C#

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, addition

I am new to C# and reflection in specific and I am trying to solve a very specific problem. I want to implement the following code using reflection (since in some machines the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dlls might not be present, in those case i will skip generating charts).

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();
string chartTitle = "Chart Title";
chart1.Titles.Add(chartTitle);
```

I figured out how to load a dll, get its class type, get/set its static/non-static properties, use constructors to create objects etc via Reflections. But I am quite lost about how to invoke "add" method on a collection.
Say, i have object Chart1 and chartTitle via Reflection, how do i implement the 3rd line of code using Reflection.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Green Apple

Comment: No need for reflection here! Simply put that code in a separate method and invoke it only if that dll can be used (or even simply...catch that exception and pass through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `object chart1` instance then you can use

`object titles = typeof(chart1).GetProperty("Titles").GetValue(chart1);`

or

`object titles = chart1.GetType().GetProperty("Titles").GetValue(chart1);`

to get the `chart1.Titles` instance.

Then use `titles.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(titles, chartTitle);` to add the new title.